# Why is the [contenthash] different in webpack?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
entry: {
    app: './src/main.js',
},
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/js/'),
    publicPath: '/js/',
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: 'chunk/[contenthash:32].js',  // use contenthash here
    hashDigestLength:32,
},
```

product a file `28024a27808de6fae79a1f5596584d3e.js`, but actually the content hash is `9c757e82e0a41d8e51228532a109a0d7`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

*webpack* uses the *old* **md4** hash *algorithm*. Also it runs this on the **base64** encoded version of your file.

Most importantly, this is done on the **non minified version** of your file. So you can't check the md4 value by comparing the hash from the filename and the actual md4 hash of the **final minified file**. They will never match.

Source: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/hashed-module-ids-plugin/

Comment: I know its an old answer :) But i'm trying to find an official writing that weback(v4 not v5 with realContentHash) is hashing based on source files and not based on output (minified). How did you come to this conclusion based on the link you provided? Thanks!

Comment: I just run md4 on my file, but base64 encoded first.

Comment: Thanks, i found [this issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/7787) i guess its "official" enough for me :)